# How to refer to the referrer in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, dom

I load a page 'A' and from that page I use a form action like this,

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/blah">
     <input id="browse4File" type="file" name="thefile" style="important:relative; width: 300px; top:75px; left:20px; "><br/>
     <input id="la" type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="UPLOAD"  style="position:relative; font-size:14px; left:300px; top:70px;"/>
</form>
<div id="RetMessage" style="position:relative; left:30px; top:70px; color:#a22; font-size:14px;">This is some comment that needs to disappear</div>
```

This form calls another page 'B', but It does not open that page directly with a `window.open`.  I think that it is referred to as a CGI request, not an AJAX request.  The 'B' page in its JavaScript needs to access the contents of page 'A' to make modifications.  I have tried many ways of accessing this:

```
document.parent.getElementById('RetMessage').innerHTML
document.referrer...
document.opener...
window.parent...
```

I have not succeeded to gain access the the referring page

Is there a genius in the house to help me with this.  It appears to me that the referring page is not linked in the DOM to the referred page.  Is there any other way to achieve this

Help!

Dennis

Comment: Try `window.opener`, but you may not be able to access all properties depending upon the domains.

Comment: @ExplosionPills — That's only if A opened B in a new window. That is no suggestion that that is the case here.

Comment: @Quentin true, this is why I posted a comment and not an answer

Comment: @Quentin,  I understand now.  I already tried opener, I just did not list it in my question.  I did say above that I call another page 'B', but I misreported that.  I used a form action "/process" which uses python to open a new page.  So the DOM link is not there, because 'A' is not the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It appears to me that the referring page is not linked in the DOM to the referred page

Correct. The browser has left that page. It does not continue to run a memory hungry copy of its DOM.

> Is there any other way to achieve this

Use `XMLHttpRequest` to load the source of that page and parse it.

This will, obviously, be limited in that JS manipulations of the DOM won't automatically run and the Same Origin Policy will apply.

Comment: Am I to understand that I could not make changes to the existing 'A' page from page 'B' no matter what?

Comment: There is no existing A page. The browser left it (at least, that is usually the case, there are sometimes exceptions when frames or new windows are in play). There is an entry in the history which says it has been there before, but that is all.

Comment: I see that I need another plan.  In that case I will be needing a return event to page 'A', in order to process the outcome left in python.  Any ideas, @Quentin?

Comment: thank you for your advice, I believe that you explained it to me best.  So, your answer satisfies the question.  And consequently I had to find another way of doing this.
Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can't, there will be a lot of security issues if one page can access the DOM of the previous page.... then, the previous... then the previous....

however, you can call page B with the content of retMessage in the query string, but be aware that end user can modify it.

Comment: What security issues would there be (other than ones which are already solved by the Same Origin Policy and other standard browser security restrictions)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Mleblanc.  I see the security issue there.  Good point...